# Fundamental difference between a Ethernet (networking) driver and a pcie driver

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, pcie

May be its a dumb question but can somebody explain the fundamental difference when you say a pcie or a Ethernet drivers. As such there are many networking cards with pcie interface. 
Consider below two hardwarwe example and please help me understand how a driver developer has to differ in his approach in both cases for writing corresponding driver.

1. A typical pcie Lan card which helps the host to connect to the network
2. Some pcie card which has complete TCP/UDP stack on the device itself and need to pump only payload from the incoming packets.

Please ask questions if not clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do refer to the "TCP Offload engine" on your second item on your list? As per this Wikipedia article the _vanilla_ Linux kernel doesn't support it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine#Support_in_Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCIe is used to communicate with your local network card. The actual network card uses the ethernet protocol to communicate with external network devices. These protocols can also be used within the OS to emulate such devices as well.

Here is an extremely basic graphical depiction that I put together for you:

[image]

Additionally, please note that ethernet is indeed a protocol and not a type of device. For instance, both fibre interfaces and rj45 copper cable interfaces can run via ethernet protocol, to name just a couple.

TCP/UDP stack is handled by the kernel/OS entirely, not by the hardware in between.

Answer (score 2):

While this is off topic…

### [PCI Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)

… is a machine bus interface for *very* high throughput, *very* low latency communication between internal and, more recently, peripheral computer hardware components.

### [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)

… is a networking protocol usually used in interfaces with high throughput, low latency communication between computers in a local area network. It is not restricted to particular routing or connection layer protocols on top of it like IP, TCP and UDP.

An Ethernet adapter device may be connected to the rest of a computer by a PCI Express bus.

Comment: I want to understand the difference from a driver developer point of view in both cases(see the example I gave). LDD3 have separate chapter for networking and pcie drivers. A networking driver can have a pcie interface.

Comment: Start to read about the physical and informational details of the two protocols then.

Comment: @Bhupendra Dubey LDD3 like this: http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ I guess. Sorry for my snarky comment on the question. I shouldn't read that much askubuntu on a single day.

Comment: @MadMike Yes I meant same LDD3. I wanted to understand basic difference in approach for developing a driver in both cases(pcie and network)